# Activate a thread based on another thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I have my `main` script where I am searching for a specific value (e.g. reading input). When I find it, i want to blink a led (*using a raspberry pi*):

- On  - sleep
- Off - sleep

x2

The problem is that blinking is blocking my main thread and I want to avoid this. I would like to have some:

```
if specific_value_is_found:
    blink_b = True
    blink_b = False
```

And the `run()` method to look like this:

```
while True:
    if blink_b:
        blink()
```

Where `blink_b` would be a global variable. I know this is a silly example and will probably not work but I hope this gives a better understanding for what I want to do.

I've searched for `queues` and it looks like it could fit here ( but it seems to me like a waste of memory to declare `X` instances of threads objects and run -> kill them each time i want to blink a led - *and it works for limited number of blinking only*). I've also look at `threading.lock` it is close to what I want to do but it's not the same thing.

Could you please give me some ideas?

Comment: Have a look at `threading.Condition`. It allows your main thread to set the condition, and the other thread to non-busy wait for it: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Condition Note that Python is restricted regarding parallel work in threads, so you might want to use `multiprocessing` module instead of threads; it also offers `multiprocessing.Condition`.

Comment: I think the ```blink_b = True``` ````blink_b = False``` sequence is happening too fast. You may want to sleep intermittently there so that the second thread can detect the value as True. I admit though, this solution is not great at all. :/

Comment: @ypnos I just came from reading that before asking this question. I don't know how to use it. I've seen an example where you lock the thread passing a lock object but then I got lost

Comment: I would run `while True:` all time in one separated Thread - and then there is no need to create and kill it again and again. Eventually I would use `running = True` and `while running` to gracefully end this thread without killing proces. Threads should use the same memery so I would use global `blink_b` to inform other thread to blink - and it should use `blink_b = False` to not repeate it again and again.

Answer (score 0):

I would run all time thread which control lead and use global `blink_b = True` to inform it to start blinking. This thead should also set `blink_b = False`, not main thread.

I would also use `running = True` to gracefully stop this thread at the end of searching.

```
import threading
import time

def blinking_thread():
    global blink_running
    global blink_b

    print('blink: start')

    #blink_running = True
    while blink_running:
        #time.sleep(0.1) # to use less CPU

        if blink_b:
            blink_b = False
            for _ in range(2):
                #led_on()
                print('blink: led_on')
                time.sleep(0.5)
                #led_off()
                print('blink: led_off')
                time.sleep(0.5)

    print('blink: finish')    

def searching_thread():
    global blink_running
    global blink_b

    # simulate long running code which sometimes want to blink
    for x in range(30):
        print('search:', x)
        time.sleep(1)
        # blink if found
        if x % 5 == 0:
           blink_b = True

# --- main ---

blink_b = False
blink_running = True

# start blinking thread
b_t = threading.Thread(target=blinking_thread)
b_t.start()

# start searching thread
s_t = threading.Thread(target=searching_thread)
s_t.start()

# wait for end of searching thread
s_t.join() #

# stop while-loop in blinkling thread
blink_running = False

# wait for end of blinkling thread
b_t.join()
```

---

The only problem - if it finds many values when led is blinking then it will blink again only once because it uses `blink_b` which can keep information only about one blink. To blink for every value found in short time `blink_b` would have to be list (or queue) to keep many `True`.

Comment: Thank you! This helps me a lot! Could you please explain me what would have happened if I don't use `st_join()` and `b_t.join()` ? I mean why wouldn't I just let them run without joining them ?

Comment: try it and you will see :)

Comment: if you don't wait for end of threads then Python ends executing code (because there is nothing do in main thread) and it automatically destroys threads - so code should not work.

Comment: My main is a while loop so this is why I didn't understand. Thank you!

Comment: @furas What's the reason to prefer busy wait over synchronization primitives like threading.Condition where the thread can sleep? Too cumbersome?

Comment: @ypnos I never had to synchronize threads so this version version was my first idea - and I think it can be easier for beginners. But if you have experience with Condition then you could create own version - it can be also useful (even for me) to compare different solutions.

Comment: I am just curious as I didn't use it myself before and you are Python expert here. I will keep it in mind for a time when I will need something like this in Python :)